# Problem with testing whether a function has been run

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs

I'm new to testing. I've tried to research this, but with no luck.

Problem is, that I'm trying to test my app root file, called `couples2.ts`, which is the entry for my NodeJS/TypeScript app.

It looks like this:

```
import App from "./app";

const app = new App();
app.run()
```

Now I'm trying to test whether the `run()` function has been called, and so I wrote this `couples2.test.ts` file with the following code, but it says that tests failed and the reason is that it's been called 0 times.

```
import App from "./app";

jest.mock('./app');

describe('couples2.ts file', () => {
    it('should run the `run` function', function () {
        const app = new App();
        expect(app.run).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE #1

I rewrote the code to be more correct, but still getting 0 calls.

`couples2.test.ts`

```
import couples2 from "./couples2";

jest.mock('./couples2');

describe('couples2.ts file', () => {
    it('should run the `run` function', function () {
        expect(couples2.run).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
})
```

`couples2.ts`

```
import App from "./app";

const app = new App();
app.run()

export default app;
```

Answer (score 0):

Test passed with the following code:

```
import couples2 from "./couples2";

jest.mock('./app');

describe('couples2.ts file', () => {
    it('should run the `run` function', function () {
        expect(couples2.run).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
})
```

I won't delete the question in case someone encounters a similar problem in the future.